# IP Camera does not show open ports for RTP streaming but shows RTSP port open

Tags: nmap, rtp, rtsp

I ran nmap on my IP camera to see what ports are open. I see a RTSP port open on port no 554, as expected. However, I do not see any ports open for RTP-RTCP streaming.

Here is the output of nmap:

```
    PORT      STATE    SERVICE
    22/tcp    filtered ssh
    80/tcp    open     http
    554/tcp   open     rtsp
    8000/tcp  open     http-alt
    8200/tcp  open     trivnet1
    9010/tcp  open     sdr
    9020/tcp  open     tambora
    49152/tcp open     unknown
```

As I understand, if I send a RTSP command to the RTSP server, I get a SDP or some such presentation providing the port where I can get the RTP/RTCP streams which would be on UDP ports. Is my expectation incorrect? The camera does support H.264, RTSP, RTP, RTCP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default nmap options only scan for TCP services (and [even then only the top 1000 most common](https://serverfault.com/a/391797/37681) ports).

[UDP portscanning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_scanner#UDP_scanning)  is more difficult and therefore not done by default.

Please take a look at for instance the nmap manual for more detail on UDP scanning:  https://nmap.org/book/scan-methods-udp-scan.html